# Python & Beautifulsoup web scraping - select a paragraph with a specific child tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to isolate the "text of interest" text from the last paragraph in the following sequence:

```
<div class='div_name_class'>
<p>
   <span class='class_name_1' title='title1'>val1</span>
   <span class='class_name_1' title='title2'>val2</span>
</p>
<p><span class='class_name_2'><em>text of no interest</em></span>text of interest</p>
```

I tried so far with:

```
print soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'class_name_2'}).parent.text

print soup.find('em').parent.parent.text
```

but both return: "text of no interesttext of interest"

I'm aware that the "text of interest" can be separated from the above result but it doesn't look like an elegant solution.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `extract` to remove the `em` tag as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class='div_name_class'>
<p>
   <span class='class_name_1' title='title1'>val1</span>
   <span class='class_name_1' title='title2'>val2</span>
</p>
<p><span class='class_name_2'><em>text of no interest</em></span>text of interest</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
p = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'class_name_2'}).parent
p.span.em.extract()
print p.text
```

This would display:

```
text of interest
```